# Home studio minimum setting and cost

Tags: home-studio

What would be the minimum requirement neccessary for audio (music) home studio?

And what would be the minimum cost?

what software and hardware would you recommend?

Comment: What do you want to do with your home studio? You can do limited multi-tracking with an iPad and Garage Band.

Comment: I want to be able to record music using virtual instruments and be able to record my voice and do some multi-tracking. (8 tracks would be sufficient, I guess.)

Comment: What do you want to do with the recordings? If these are demos strictly for your own use, you can get away with quite a bit less than if you want to upload tracks and attempt to sell them or even use them for publicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Software: [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm) costs $60 for personal or commercial use that grosses less than $20k annually.
- Audio interface: used MOTU 828 mk2, easily found on eBay or Craigslist for under $300.
- PC or mac with 4GB+ of RAM and a reasonably modern dual-core CPU. Under $1000 for a desktop, under $1500 for a laptop

I'd start with Reaper on whatever machine you have now, and upgrade as necessary. Buy as much stuff used as you can - there is a ton of awesome gear out there on eBay and craigslist.

Comment: Note that Reaper is not feature limited when run in demo mode (at least it was this way when I tried it) so you can really experiment with it without any risk. In addition, it is *possible* to use your existing on-board audio: try ASIO4ALL. I would say a core2duo class of processor is probably the lowest you want. A regular P4 processor is probably not going to work well at even a basic level. Once you get this working and get a feel for the workflow, you can look into investing more cash.